# Concat case statement

Tags: t-sql, case, concatenation, isnull

I'm very new to coding but I am trying to work out how I can (or if I can) concat the code below ideally excluding any null returns separated with commas.

So an example would be:-

Germany, Latvia, Norway

Great Britain, France, Latvia

Any help and explanations would be greatly appreciated.

```
Select 
*,

CASE 
WHEN PT_ID1 != 0 THEN 'Germany' 
WHEN PT_ID2 != 0 THEN 'Great Britain'
WHEN PT_ID3 != 0 THEN 'France'
WHEN PT_ID4 != 0 THEN 'Latvia'
WHEN PT_ID5 != 0 THEN 'Norway'
END AS Country

FROM      CTE2 C1
FULL JOIN CTE  C ON  C.PT_ID1 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE3 D ON  D.PT_ID3 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE4 E ON  E.PT_ID4 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE5 F ON  F.PT_ID5 = C1.PT_ID2

order by MRN asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different `CASE` statements for each country

```
Select 
*,

 STUFF(CASE WHEN PT_ID1 != 0 THEN ', Germany' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN PT_ID2 != 0 THEN ', Great Britain' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN PT_ID3 != 0 THEN ', France' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN PT_ID4 != 0 THEN ', Latvia' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN PT_ID5 != 0 THEN ', Norway' ELSE '' END, 1, 2, '') AS Country

FROM      CTE2 C1
FULL JOIN CTE  C ON  C.PT_ID1 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE3 D ON  D.PT_ID3 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE4 E ON  E.PT_ID4 = C1.PT_ID2
FULL JOIN CTE5 F ON  F.PT_ID5 = C1.PT_ID2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.